# UITableViewDataSource not refresh when trying to add another value in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, datasource

My following code is recall api again when user scroll down end of UITableView and found there is another page is still available from API.

**ViewController**

```
func loadMoreJobs(page: Int) {
        let params = [
            "session_token": JBCSettings.sessionToken,
            "page_count": "\(page)"
        ]
        JBCService.shared.getService(request: JBCRouter.jobs(params), callbackSuccess: { (obj: ObjectJobs?) in
            if obj?.status == 1 {

                self.jobsDataSource = JBCJobsDataSource()
                self.jobsDataSource?.jobTableView = self.jobTableView
                self.jobsDataSource?.job = obj.jobList
                self.jobsDataSource?.isEnd = (obj?.end)!

            }
        }) { (status, obj) in

        }
    }
```

and **JBCJobsDataSource**

```
class JBCJobsDataSource: NSObject {

    var job = [JobObject]() {
        didSet {
            reloadTableView()
        }
    }
    var isEnd: Int = 0

    weak var jobTableView: UITableView? {
        didSet {
            setupTableView()
        }
    }

    func setupTableView() {
        if jobTableView != nil {
            jobTableView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            jobTableView!.delegate =  self
            jobTableView!.dataSource = self
            jobTableView!.register(UINib(nibName: "JobCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: JobCell.cellIdentify())
        }
    }

    func reloadTableView() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.jobTableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

extension JBCJobsDataSource: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func dataForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath:IndexPath) -> JobObject {
        return job[indexPath.row]
    }

    .
    .
    .

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if ((indexPath.row+1) == job.count && isEnd == 1) {
            _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func update() {
        JBCServiceExecute.jobNoti(page: true)
    }
}
```

And the problem is `isEnd` variable is never updated inside **JBCJobsDataSource**. That's why code is still calling to `loadMoreJobs` even there is no more record found. That's why please let me know how to refresh updated response to

```
        self.jobsDataSource = JBCJobsDataSource()
        self.jobsDataSource?.jobTableView = self.jobTableView
        self.jobsDataSource?.job = obj.jobList
        self.jobsDataSource?.isEnd = (obj?.end)!
```

Comment: have you check what value it contain obj?.end

Answer (score 0):

> And the problem is isEnd variable is never updated inside
>   JBCJobsDataSource.

That's because you are creating a new `JBCJobsDataSource` instance each time in the callback of the `JBCService.shared.getService` method:

```
// the below line is the reason of the problem:
self.jobsDataSource = JBCJobsDataSource()

self.jobsDataSource?.jobTableView = self.jobTableView
self.jobsDataSource?.job = obj.jobList
self.jobsDataSource?.isEnd = (obj?.end)!
```

As mentioned, the code is saying: "create a new instance each time the `callbackSuccess` has been called", obviously each instance has its own independent values for its properties.

So, to fix it probably you should instantiate `jobsDataSource` one time in the life cycle of your view controller (where you are calling `loadMoreJobs`), you could do it like this:

```
var jobsDataSource = JBCJobsDataSource()
```

with removing the line of:

```
self.jobsDataSource = JBCJobsDataSource()
```

Or: if there is no need to use `jobsDataSource` directly when accessing the view controller, you could declare it as *lazy* property:

```
lazy var jobsDataSource = JBCJobsDataSource()
```

---

Btw, for handling the dataSource and the delegate for the view controller table view, you don't have to declare `jobTableView` in `JBCJobsDataSource`, instead, you could do this:

After instantiating `jobsDataSource`:

```
self.jobsDataSource?.jobTableView.dataSource = jobsDataSource
self.jobsDataSource?.jobTableView.delegate = jobsDataSource
```

Comment: Hi, I just called `loadMoreJobs` inside `JBCServiceExecute.jobNoti(page: true)`. I've created separate `JBCJobsDataSource` for reusable purpose.